# VBA button - based on a cell value rather than ActiveCell

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA and trying to update the code below to look for a value within a cell rather than ActiveCell. Specifically, I want to find the row below a cell with a value of "B." (e.g.), copy the 3 rows below, and paste+insert those 3 rows directly beneath the copied 3 rows. *Effectively, I am trying to get my VBA button to work without asking users to first click into a specific cell.* My current code, based on ActiveCell, is working well as long as you are in the correct cell. Any insight would be helpful.

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim NextRow As Long
    Dim I As Long

    With Range(ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=2), ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0))
        NextRow = .Row + .Rows.Count
        Rows(NextRow & ":" & NextRow + .Rows.Count * (1) - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        .EntireRow.Copy Rows(NextRow & ":" & NextRow + .Rows.Count * (1) - 1)
        .Resize(.Rows.Count * (1 + 1)).Sort key1:=.Cells(1, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: In which column do you search for 'value of "B." (e.g.)'? In B:B and you tried a question type  2 in one? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next updated code. It will require the string/text of the cell you need to identify (in an InputBox). For testing reason, I used the string "testSearch". Please, put it in the cell of A:A to be identified and test it. Then, you can use whatever string you need...

```
Sub testTFindCellFromString()
  Dim NextRow As Long, I As Long, strSearch As String
  Dim sh As Worksheet, actCell As Range, rng As Range

   strSearch = InputBox("Please, write the string from the cell to be identified", _
                      "Searching string", "testSearch")
   If strSearch = "" Then Exit Sub
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   Set rng = sh.Range("A1:A" & sh.Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
   Set actCell = testFindActivate("testSearch", rng)
   If actCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

   With Range(actCell.Offset(2, 0), actCell.Offset(0, 0))
        NextRow = .Row + .Rows.Count
        Rows(NextRow & ":" & NextRow + .Rows.Count * (1) - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        .EntireRow.Copy Rows(NextRow & ":" & NextRow + .Rows.Count * (1) - 1)
        .Resize(.Rows.Count * (1 + 1)).Sort key1:=.Cells(1, 1)
    End With
  Debug.Print actCell.Address
End Sub
Private Function testFindActivate(strSearch As String, rng As Range) As Range
   Dim actCell As Range
   Set actCell = rng.Find(What:=strSearch)
   If actCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox """" & strSearch & """ could not be found..."
        Exit Function
   End If
   Set testFindActivate = actCell
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your rapid response! I am searching "B." in column A. I apologize, but I don't quite follow the two scenarios you listed in your answer.

Comment: Can you better explain what yoy need? Did you try the code cganging BB.:B with A:A?

Comment: Yes, thank you. As a newbie, I am not sure how to combine the codes, particularly with your suggestion to not use selection. Do I still use 'With'?
    
'With Range(actCell2.Offset(rowOffset:=3), actCell2.Offset(rowOffset:=1))' or 'actCell2.Select.Range.Offset...'

Comment: 'Set rng = sh.Range("A:A" & sh.Range("B." & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)'

Comment: @Brian: Why `actCell2`? OK. I will transform my `Sub` in a `Function` and I will integrate it in your code...

Comment: My plan was to use this code for several buttons (within the same sheet) and to specify the search item within the code. For example, actCell1 = search for "A.", actCell2 = search for "B." You've helped me a lot, so thank you!

Comment: @Brian: Glad being able to help you! Now, it should me sample to replace the `InputBox` with the string to be searched and define `rng` according to your need...